# Does google chrome extensions support applets? Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to trigger an applet in my google chrome extension.
Below is my background.html file.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function callJavaFile(){
var mac = applett.javaMethod();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onclick="callJavaFile()">
<object name="applett" code="ParamTest.class" archive="filepath.jar" width="10" height="10">
</object>
</html>
```

But I am getting this error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method"

What am I missing?

Regards,
Nikhil

Comment: You should be happy you don't get more errors. Are you using `manifest_version` 1 ? Inline scripts are not allowed any more. Read more **[here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2.html)**.

Comment: Thank you so much for that info. Had missed so many updates regarding the migration of manifest 1 to 2. Much appreciate the link. But do the second version allow me to have an applet in it? Because I did not find any relevance of applet update in that?

Comment: I don't really know. I play around quite a lot with extensions (and relevant docs) and I haven't seen anything about applets being not allowed. On the other hand, I haven't try to use them so I don' really know. If I had to guess I'd say "Why not ?". But, regarding the code you posted above, you need to at least get rid of the inline scripting.